# Create temporary function in Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I am doing some querying in Amazon Athena (which is using Presto from my understanding). I would like to create a temporary function in similar fashion as in [Presto](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/create-function.html):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION square(x int)
RETURNS int
RETURN x * x

SELECT square(col) from table
```

Is it possible to do it like this in Athena? The only [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-udf.html) I found is not very understandable for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Athena provides an extension mechanism of User-Defined-Functions (UDF) using AWS Lambda. It gives you more flexibility and scale of the functionality in your UDF. The tutorial you mentioned in your question is explaining how to develop the Lambda function and deploy it to the cloud, and then how to call it from Athena.